Can I swap out the guts of a 200A panel
I have a customer who wants his panel changed. The load center plastic is cracking on the main lugs. The panel is recessed and a tough spot to replace, so I was wondering if I could just change the inside bus?
It’s an old ITE panel that was bought out by Siemens.

(a) pictures might help; (b) check with a Siemens dealer (an electrical supply house that sells Siemens, not Home Depot/Lowes/etc.); (c) phrasing raises issues about a non-electrician (based on the question) doing serious electrical work on someone else's home, which is not allowed in most jurisdictions.

1 - the true answer may depend upon the building code for your customer's home, if something like this needs to be done by a licensed electrician or not, where is he located?
2 - unless you are confident with this, I would leave it to a pro, you don't want to make a rookie mistake and his house burns down.

If you're allowed to do the work (and if you're a licensed electrician, you should probably already know the answer, or know who to ask), you also need to be concerned with anything else that might need to be updated, in case replacing a panel causes the need to bring everything involved up to current code requirements.  It's possible that your local jurisdiction wouldn't allow anything grandfathered in this scenario, so the scope of the work might be more than you expect it to be.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement DIYers, but people working for hire.

1 or 2 things here are definite;  Either you are not qualified to do this work  and/or you overlooked close and easy sources for this information.  I too vote to close

You can't just slap any old panel interior in there.  NEC 110.12 and 110.3. Sometimes you get lucky and the panel box hasn't changed and the mounting points are identical, but I tried that with Siemens and it didn't work because they change a lot.   If you need a universal kit that will work on any box, Eaton makes retrofit interiors. However they are quite demanding on enclosure space, so you won't get as many breaker spaces as you had before.  Note NEC 2023 requires that any panel replacement also include an outside disconnect be added to the house. Also you CAN'T do this "live".

If you can locate a "retro fit" kit for that particular panel then you can go ahead and use that. This may require shopping around the various manufacturers.
If you cannot locate one designed to fit with the existing panel then you will need to replace the entire enclosure.
